# Storing Lucene index in a BigTable database

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, hbase, bigtable

I have a BigTable database that contains data from different sources, and I'm trying to index all the data with Lucene.

Creating the index should not be a problem as long as I manage to query the Database in the right way, but when it comes to storing the index, I'm getting really confused. I did some research and I found two possible ways, Storing them in the Hard Disk which is good for storing a heavy sized index, but it's slower when doing a search,or store them in the Ram which is fast when doing a search but expensive when it comes to the size.

I found and tried many examples of saving the index in the Hard disk, 
but I can't find an example that gives a possible solution for a production environment (neither the Hdd or Ram seem right).

I found these 2 old links [link1](https://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/lucene-with-hbase-td3080212.html) [link2](https://grokbase.com/t/hadoop/common-user/116jzwhd6k/lucene-with-hbase) talking about a possible specific implementation that integrates Lucene with Hbase. In the case of BigTable, could a specific implementation be the only solution ?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this [link](https://medium.com/@duhroach/the-right-cloud-bigtable-index-makes-all-the-difference-3bcabe9bd65a) it talks a bout indexing in Big Table with out Lucene but it could help

Comment: I already took a look at that and it still don't solve the main issue. I'm starting the think that the only way is building everything from scratch: creating Lucene index from BigTable, Storing the index somewhere in HDD (Lucene specific format), store it also in BigTable as plain text for updating purposes and to prevent failure or corruption of data.